# Can I change the base code of my mobile application entirely and still reserve my download count on Google play and Apple store?

Tags: android, ios

We're doing a new mobile app for a business and we're going to use a new code base and basically build it from scratch, they already have a mobile app and the new one should replace the old on both google play and apple store and I needed to know if that is going to reset the download count that already exists for the old app or not? 
your help is much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I needed to know if that is going to reset the download count that
>   already exists for the old app or not?

No. As long as you keep the `applicationId` as well as the signing keystore same as your older release. You can simply upload your app as an update to your previous app.